# Find the number of necessary fixed point iterations to get error less than $10^{-15}$

Tags: numerical-methods, fixed-point-iteration

Given that $s$ is a solution to the equation $x = \arccos(x)$, and assuming that we start with $x_0 = 0.5$ we want to provide an estimate for the number of steps that are necessary until $|x_n - s| < 10^{-15}$.

How do I solve this problem? I have never really used fixed point iterations to do this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do fixed point iteration, you want the derivative of the right side to be less than $1$ in absolute value, which is not the case with your iteration.  This is why your iteration fails.  When you are close to the root, the error is multiplied by the first derivative at every step.  If the first derivative is $d$ and the initial error is $e$, after $n$ steps the error will be about $ed^n$, so you want $ed^n \lt 10^{-15}$.  Now you can solve for $n$.

Comment: I assume we want to maximize the $d$ to get a bound on that expression, hence we use $d(s\approx 0.739)$, and the error is $|x_n - s| \approx | 0.5 - 0.739|$. When I put these numbers and solve for  $n$ i get a negative number as answer, did I use a wrong $s$ value?

Comment: @Geir The first derivative of $\cos$ at the fixed point in absolute value is about 0.67, and the initial error is about 0.24, so the error is about $0.24 \cdot 0.67^n$. I don't really know where this minimizing/maximizing thing came from. Note that the standard fixed point error estimate is not extremely useful because it is based on the value of the derivative at the fixed point, which is usually unknown. It works better when the method is tailored so that the derivative at the fixed point is zero by construction...but you'll get to that soon.

Answer (score 0):

If you compute with real iterations  $x_{n+1} = \arccos(x_n)$, you will **fail** already in the second step, because
$x_1=\arccos(0.5)= 1.0471975511965977,\; \arccos(x_1)=0.3060421086132657\times i$.

I explain an approximate solution for the iteration $x_{n+1} = \cos(x_n)$ with $x=0.5:$.
The convergence is obviously linear, we can assume that the difference $|x_{n+1}-x_n|$
decreases by about one bit per step. $x=0.5$ has approximately 1 bit accuracy. We have $10^{-15} \approx 2^{-49.8},$ so we expect a priori convergence after about 49 steps. Actually
the accuracy is already reached after 38 steps.

Comment: Nothing in the problem says the iteration to solve $x=f(x)$ is $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$.

Comment: @IAN: Granted, but the two iteration are the manifest choices. If you do not have $f(x)$ you cannot say anything about the number of steps.

Comment: Saying you add about one bit per step is equivalent to saying the derivative of the iteration function is about one half.  If the derivative is smaller, you will add more accuracy per step.  You are right that the convergence is linear.

Comment: I'm saying it's a matter of presentation; you should say something like "the first guess might be to try $x_{n+1}=\arccos(x)$ but that fails because ... so we instead try $x_{n+1}=\cos(x)$ and it works".